# Identify this insect

Tags: species-identification, entomology

Please help identify this insect - genus, species and anything interesting about it. Also - please outline your general methodology for identifying such insects

Note, this is [posted separately due to comments in this other thread](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FtdoD.png).

[image]

[image]

Comment: Which previous thread? Your link doesn't point to a previous thread, it points to https://i.stack.imgur.com/FtdoD.png.

Comment: @arboviral https://biology.stackexchange.com/q/64042/1486

Comment: You should add the location for all species ID questions.

Comment: It is a long-horned beetle in the genus Anoplophora. Most likely A. chinensis, A. macularia or A. oshimana.

Answer (score 4):

Okay, to identify to Order level you can use the key [here](https://www.amentsoc.org/insects/what-bug-is-this/adult-key.html) (although it's actually not as user-friendly as I'd expect; I might suggest they revise it). The key characteristic is that the forewings are uniformly hardened. So, starting at question 1:

- "Insect has wings" - yes; go to 2.
- "Two pairs of wings" - yes (wing cases/elytra are the first pair); go
  to 7.
- "Fore wings hard or leathery" - yes; go to 8.
- "Fore wings of uniform texture throughout" - yes; go to 9.
- "Fore wings (elytra) hard and veinless, meeting in centre line" -
  yes; go to 10.
- "Abdomen without forceps: elytra commonly cover whole abdomen =
  Coleoptera [beetles]".

So we know it's a **beetle**.

There's a key to beetle families [here](http://www.wildlifebcn.org/sites/bcnp.live.wt.precedenthost.co.uk/files/files/BeetleFamKey1.pdf). Starting at question 1:

- antennae are "clubbed or thickened" so go to 5.
- "Elytra covering all of abdomen" yes, go to 7.
- "Head not stretched forward into a beak" - go to 9.
- "the last few segments [of the antennae] clearly wider than the rest" - no, so go to 24.
- the elytra (wing cases aren't "soft (easily bent, folded or even 
  rolled up)" so go to 28.
- this is a tricky one, but basically you can (just) see that all the tarsi (feet) have the same number of segments, so we go to 29.
- 29: "      Beetle usually elongate and parallel-sided; antennae very long often longer than head and body; most antennal segments very elongate (at lease twice as long as wide)" - sounds like our beetle, so that makes it a longhorn beetle. (Some of the other criteria - eye nothces etc - only apply to some species, but this key is a UK-specific one).

So we have a **longhorn beetle** (Coleoptera: Cerambycidae). In theory you shouldn't need to geographical location to get this to species level as it could be an introduced species etc; in practice most keys are specific to certain geographical regions so you might need to provide the collection location to get it to species level. You could start by [Googling "longhorn beetle identification key"](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=longhorn%20beetle%20identification%20key) and give it a go though.

Comment: Well done, nice research made... +1

Comment: From overall appearance, it also looks like an Lamiinae (flat-faced longhorns).

Comment: @fileunderwater overall appearance?

Comment: would this fit the bill of Asian longhorn beetle?

Comment: @ina Flat vertical face, robust, reniform eyes etc. Still thousands of species to choose from though.

Comment: any advice on how to narrow down on the species?

Comment: Or you could just look at the picture and say "that's a longhorn beetle"